# Generic function to detect if the value is null in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find some way to detect if there are null/empty values masquerading as strings.

So far what I have been doing is filtering as follows:

```
def isnull(string):
    if string in [np.nan, 'None', '', 'NaN', 'nan', None]:
        return True
```

but the truth is that it seems to me a dirty way to do it.

I know that each thing is different but I think that when working with Pandas, it can be useful to know if there are are, at least, words like `None`, `nan's` , `null` and empty string inside a column masked as strings.

For example, if we do a `pd.isna('None')` it returns a `False`. it would be very nice to have something that detects this kind of cases.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should know what data you're working with and not try to guess them all…?!

Comment: I'm agnostic of what I can potentially receive... usually are only 'None' and 'nan' but this can change and in some cases it can be critical to detect them such as word 'null'

Comment: You can only be "agnostic" within limits. Preferably you'd define what values you regard as "null" and keep that list as short as possible, and the input needs to conform to that spec. If it's the other way around and you need to process virtually arbitrary input, then you'll need to do something like you're doing; but the longer your potential "null" list is, the greater the chance for a false positive too…

Answer (score 0):

You should know which values to expect, that said it is legitimate to try to automatize replacement.

You could convert to string and use a regex to detect the values, then use `mask`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [np.nan, 'None', '', 'NaN', 'nan', None,
                           'nAn', 'NA', 'null', 'valid', 1]})

df['col2'] = (df['col']
              .mask(df['col'].astype(str)
                    .str.fullmatch('(?:|nan?|none|null)',
                                   case=False)
                   )
             )
```

output:

```
      col   col2
0     NaN    NaN
1    None    NaN
2            NaN
3     NaN    NaN
4     nan    NaN
5    None    NaN
6     nAn    NaN
7      NA    NaN
8    null    NaN
9   valid  valid
10      1      1
```